# NLP and english dictionary database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, artificial-intelligence, nlp

Is there an open dictionary database where I can get at minimum a table of the sort:
word | part of speech ?

Ideally I would also like antonym and synonym links to other words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) will probably provide you with what you need.

Answer (score 1):

you can check [cmu dictionary](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict) it contains word and its phonetic transcriptions. it did not have links to antonyms and synonyms when i used it last time